# Question about the proof that every vector space has a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In a many of proofs of this theorem that I've seen, authors always take a set of vectors linearly independent.

My question is: does there exist a theorem that says:

> If a set of vectors in a vector space are linearly independent, then they are a basis for the vector space.

When the author takes a linearly independent set, he's not affirming the thesis?

Comment: The set of vectors must not only be linearly independent, it must also be maximal with respect to this property, only then the set qualifies as  a basis.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I think you meant "only then" instead of "then only"...

Comment: @mathbeing Yes, please excuse my poor English, and thank you.

Comment: Also notice that if $v\ne 0$, then $\{v\}$ is linearly independent

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг why the set of vectors linearly indepedent must be maximal?

Comment: @testpilot That is the definition of a basis.  It needs to span the entire vector space, so the linearly independent set has to be as large as possible, right?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of any basis are linearly independent, but not every set of linearly independent vectors is a basis: consider $\{(1,0)\}$ or $\{(1,1)\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$. But every linearly independent set *can be extended* to a basis. (*For example, $\{(1,0), (0, 1)\}$ and $\{(1,1), (-1, 1)\}$ are different bases for $\Bbb R^2$ that extend the sets just mentioned.*) In finite dimensions the proof of this is an algorithm; in general, however, you need some sort of maximality principle (the Axiom of Choice, basically).

Answer (score 0):

The important point is that if J is an independent set and x is a vector not in the span of J, then the result of adjoining x to J is also independent. This doesnt work in the more general context of R-modules.